# How to share image from recyclerView arraylist?

Tags: java, android-studio, share

I am trying to share an images from arraylist,when I click on share button app list appears to share but when I select an app to share,it shows null in another app.

please help me to find out the solution :(

here is my recycler onBindViewHolder code.

```
holder.send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
            StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());
            final String image_path = fileslist.get(position).getUri().toString();
            File share = new File(image_path);
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(share);
            Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
            shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.setType("image/");
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share to....."));
        }
    });
```

and here how my app is sharing
[image]

Comment: Why you added this `shareIntent.setType("video/*");` Type?